# Select Wayland output for QT application

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, egl, wayland, omap

I am running QT 5.11.3 on a TI embedded platform (AM5728). My display manager is wayland 1.16 (weston). The QPA for my application is Wayland-Egl.

The embedded system has both an LCD panel & HDMI output. Both are recognized and treated as independent outputs in wayland.

My question is: How can I programatically choose which wayland output my QT application starts on?

I found that if I use a mouse, the application starts on the output which the mouse is currently active on, but I need to have the application start on the specific desired output (without mouse).

Are there any back-end QPA related calls or settings which can be configured to allow this?

Thanks!